# Noetherian topological space

Tags: general-topology

I have a topology question.

> Show that in a Noetherian topological space, every non-empty closed set can be expressed as a finite union of irreducible closed sets, unique up to redundancy.

I didnt take topology course before. I am asking now just to learn. So, please show or explain me clearly the question. Thank you.

Comment: This is a standard fact. See e.g. Proposition 1.5 in [Hartshorne, _Algebraic geometry_, Ch. I] or [Lemma `0052`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0052) in the Stacks project.

Comment: Yes I saw it. And I understand the proof there. But I am confused at a point, which is that the question is said "unique up to redundancy". But the proposition in not mentioned. What is this? Please explain the point? Thank you @ZhenLin

Comment: It just means that the decomposition has no redundant components. For example, if $X \subseteq Y$, then $X \cup Y \cup Z = Y \cup Z$, i.e. you can throw away $X$.

Comment: Please can you expand your comment about "up to redundancy"? can you show it on this question? Thank you @zhenLin

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have comment points yet, I'll 'answer' (i.e. comment) from the viewpoint of algebraic geometry: if $\rm{R}$ is a Noetherian ring, then the Zariski topology has the following property: every closed subset of $\rm{Spec}(R)$ is a finite union of irreducible closed sets precisely because every ideal of $\rm{R}$ is finitely-generated.

The general topological notion of `Noetherian' is then the condition that every decreasing sequence of closed sets stabilizes.

It would be helpful if you wrote down for us your initial definition for a topological space to be Noetherian.

Comment: Thank you. I understand basically. :) but as Zhen Lin said, I saw the proposion at suggested book. And I understand the proof there. But I am confused at a point, which is that the question is said "unique up to redundancy". What is this? Please explain the point? Thank you

Comment: Dear @fractionfield if you look at my another question, I will be happy and upvote them so that you reach comment point immediately. Please look:)http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684014/irreducible-quadratic-polynomial